# Process XSLT with javascript instructions on the Server side in JAVA

Tags: javascript, java, xslt, saxon, xalan

I've received an XSLT file that contains embedded javascript code, but is not compatible with any browser except Internet Explorer (Chrome is not showing everything, firefox just shows an exception)

```
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:js="urn:custom-javascript"
```

...

```
<msxsl:script language="JavaScript" implements-prefix="js"><![CDATA[
function doSomething() { ... }
function doStuff() { ... }
]]></msxsl:script>
```

As the client-side conversion is not perfect... I was hoping that server-side conversion could maybe fix some problems. Unfortunately, I can't make any change to the given XSLT file, but I do get errors on the server side :

```
Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: The first argument to the non-static Java function 'doSomething' is not a valid object reference.
```

After some research, it seems that Javascript code can't be used with Xalan or Saxon... but I was not able to find any alternatives (other than changing the XSLT code of course...)

Are there any other librairies that could process XSLT with Javascript on server side? Or should I simply stop trying to find a solution on my side.

Comment: Any use of extension elements and script is dependent on the XSLT processor, given `xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:js="urn:custom-javascript"` and that it works with IE the processor is MSXML 3 or 6 and you could run it on any Windows OS using COM automation as provided by many scripting languages or programming languages on Windows. But outside of Windows there is no support for MSXML.

Comment: How difficult would it be to convert the Javascript?

Comment: I don't know, I don't have any real knowledge in XSLT. I just have to include an XSLT into our product, but this file was developped by another company. I'll contact them to check if they can change it.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add an answer for the sake of closure: you are correct that Javascript extension functions in an msxsl:script tag will not work with Saxon, and that the only way to make the stylesheet work under Saxon is to rewrite the extension functions using Saxon's equivalent facilities.